# Pandas - Calculate which dates another date is between

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataset where each record has 5 date values, and then another date variable. I want to pull either the smallest of the 5 dates that's greater than the other variable, or else the largest of the 5 dates that's smaller. Example:

```
date1 date2 date3 date4 date5 date_var result1 result2
jan1  feb1  apr1  sep1  dec1  mar1     apr1    feb1
```

So basically the goal is to find out which of the two dates date_var is between (feb-apr here) and then pull either the smaller or larger one. If it matters the input data is already cleaned such that date1 < date2 < date3 < date4 < date5 for all dates, although there is a possibility of them being na.

My solution was this:

```
df.loc[df.date_var > date5,'result2'] = date5
df.loc[(df.date_var <= date5) & (df.date_var > date4),'result2'] = date4
df.loc[(df.date_var <= date4) & (df.date_var > date3),'result2'] = date3
...
```

but this is very slow. Is there a faster way to do this operation, or is this just something that's going to be slow? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify what should be the result for this example? I cannot see if any of the days are between result1 and result2 for your example. Is the answer NA here?

Comment: result1 and result2 are the output of the function, you can see in the example date_var is between date2 and date3 so those results are just the value of those columns: feb1 and apr1.

Comment: I see. why don't you extract not na dates, and return +1 index of date as result1 and -1 index as result two (assuming that the days are sorted, if not sort them and remove na values then do this.).

Comment: I'm not following, can you put the code you'd use? The result is going to depend on which two dates date_var is in between, so I'm trying to figure out how to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my understanding of the question.

- We are given 5 dates such that d1 < d2 < d3 < d4 < d5.
- We are also given a target date.
- Find i such that d_i <= target < d_i+1
- result1 is d_i, and result2 is d_i+1

Here is my approach:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
Record = namedtuple('Record', 'd1 d2 d3 d4 d5 target')

df = pd.DataFrame([
    Record('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-09-01', '2019-12-01', '2019-03-01'),
    Record('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-12-01', '2020-03-01'),
])
df = df.astype('datetime64[D]')

# define function to find lower, upper bounding dates
def find_bound(s, target, metric='min'):
    assert isinstance(s, pd.Series)
    
    if metric == 'min':
        return s[s <= target].max()
    else:
        return s[s > target].min()

df['min'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_bound(x['d1':'d5'], x['target'], 'min'), axis=1)
df['max'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_bound(x['d1':'d5'], x['target'], 'max'), axis=1)

# verify that lower, upper bounds are correct
df['validate'] = (df['min'] <= df['target']) & (df['target'] < df['max'])
print(df.transpose())

                   0           1
d1        2019-01-01  2020-01-01
d2        2019-02-01  2020-02-01
d3        2019-04-01  2020-04-01
d4        2019-09-01  2020-09-01
d5        2019-12-01  2020-12-01
target    2019-03-01  2020-03-01
min       2019-02-01  2020-02-01 <- result 1
max       2019-04-01  2020-04-01 <- result 2
validate        True        True
```

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I was looking for thanks. Looking for the max that's less or the min that's greater, that should be much quicker than checking each of the 4 intervals to see which it falls in. Thanks.